# SailsJS not able to do multiple 'find'

Tags: forms, controller, find, sails.js, undefined

here's the idea: I want to do a little website/manager game, and I'm trying to do a form to create a new player. I need to be able to select a position ("poste"), a city ("ville_naissance"), and some skills, and I'm stuck doing this.

Via the PlayerController, I'm able to put the cities list OR the postes list OR the skills list, but not the three together.

Here's my code :

**Player controller**

```
  'new': function(req, res) {
City.find( function foundCities(err, cities) {
  if(err) return next(err);

  res.view({
    cities: cities
  });
});

Poste.find( function foundPostes(err, postes) {
  if(err) return next(err);

  res.view({
    postes: postes
  });
});

Skill.find( function foundSkills(err, skills) {
  if(err) return next(err);

  res.view({
    skills: skills
  });
});
}
```

The new.ejs file is a simple form with inputs, selects and radios, for example :
**postesList.ejs**

```
<% _.each(postes, function(poste) {%>
<input type="radio" name="poste" value="<%= poste.ID %>" data-model="poste"/> <%= poste.poste %><br>
```

And of course, the error says

> postes is not defined

I'm pretty sure that I'm not doing it right, but I really don't see how it should be.
Thanks!

Comment: Call `res.view` after all 3 finds have returned their callback. You may use [`async.parallel`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel)

Comment: Thx, I tried this before and it didnt work, and now it's working, I dnt know what I did the first time but it's fixed now...